# How can I access the body of the request from this middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, body-parser

I'm trying to access the body of the request in a middleware in order to perform it only if a specific field has changed (ereasing pictures only if new pictures got uploaded), but I'm not able to access the body.

I've tried to install and configure cors as well as reconfiguring `body-parser` in the route-specific file, as well as shuffling around the code, but nothing has helped (this is what was suggested in other questions).

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require('lodash');

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

//MIDDLEWARE
router.use("/immobili/:_id/edit", urlencodedParser, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    const requestedId = req.params._id;

    Immobile.findOne({ _id: requestedId }, (err, immobile) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        immobile.immagini = [];
        cancellaFoto(immobile);
        if (this.cancellato) {
            return setTimeout(next, 1000);
        } else {
            return console.log("Aborted");
        }
    });
});

//EDIT PUT ROUTE
router.put("/immobili/:_id/edit", upload.array('immaginePrincipale', 30), function (req, res) {

    const requestedId = req.params._id;
    const dati = req.body;
    const proprietaImmagini = req.files;
    const immagini = proprietaImmagini.map(function (immagine) {
        //console.log(immagine.path);
        return immagine.path;
    });

    let vetrina;
    req.body.vetrina === 'on' ? vetrina = true : vetrina = false;

    Immobile.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: requestedId }, {
        numeroScheda: dati.numeroScheda,

        //[... ALL DATA ... ]

        immagini: immagini,
    }, function (err, updatedImmobile) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        res.redirect("/immobili/" + req.body.categoria + "/" + _.toLower(req.body.localita) + "/" + requestedId);
    });
});
```

This is the form I'm using to send the data:

```
<form action="/immobili/<%= immobile._id %>/edit?_method=PUT" method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

//[ ... FORM INPUTS ... ]

<input type="file" name="immaginePrincipale" multiple="multiple" id="immaginePrincipale"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Pubblica">
    </form>
```

I would expect to access the body of the request in the middleware but I get only an empty object in return.

Comment: how are you sending your request?

Comment: With a form, I'll add it in the question!

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I'm using a post request and method-override for that!